# Is there any way to add "this" key word automatically to class fields in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, intellij-14

For example, instead of this:

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

I want to get this:

```
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
```

It appears I used such setting in Eclipse, but I can't find it for Idea...

Comment: Why do you want to add `this` keyword as Compiler already do this for you.

Comment: @IlyasSoomro, my colleagues think that this adds readability to code, but I always forget to do this manually :)

Comment: @ytkopobot, this seems a good reason.

Comment: @IlyasSoomro, mostly, it's usefull while code review, when you look only at changed line

Comment: Thanks for clearifying. If you ask me, I personally don't like reading code with many `this`. IDEs now-a-days color the identifier of field variables, so unless you're using notepad (which you aren't), I don't see how it increases readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use an inspection for that.

- search inspections for "this"
- enable "Instance field access not qualified with 'this'" in "Code style issues" (see capture below)

[image: enable "Instance field access not qualified with 'this'"]

Now IntelliJ Idea will highlight not qualified access and you can refactor (<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> under linux) to fix the issue (see capture below)

[image: fix the issue]

(screenshots from IntelliJ Idea 12 under linux)